# Create 24-hour Vertical Timeline with Google Charts

Tags: charts, google-visualization

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wm1qonvu/1/

I need to create an interactive Timeline with Google Charts. I am following the example here: 
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline#controlling-the-colors
and my JSFiddle contains that code.

However, what I need is

- Re-orient the timeline vertically
- Get rid of the example's Categories
  (e.g. "Magnolia Room," "Willow Room") -- I don't have those
  categories, I only have vertical time steps.

I can keep their scheduled activities, but the timeline needs to look like this:

```
8:00 -------
8:30 [..]---
9:00 -------
9:30 [..] [..]
```

Any quick tweaks possible here?

Some additional questions,

- How do I customize the increments (e.g. 5, 10, 15 min. intervals)
- How do I set the min/max to 0:00 to 23:59
- Overlaps in the Vertical would be shown side-by-side, is that supported?
- How was the y-axis chosen as "Room," even if I remove it?

**EDIT** I was surprised to see this exchange in 2011-2012 where someone asked about vertical timelines (time on the Y-axis) and the response was that it's flat out not supported! I.e. only horizontal time values are supported. Could this be true? Has anything changed?
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-visualization-api/K0VFWCkd_Nw

Comment: using the Timeline chart, vertical simply isn't supported, as well as custom increments -- for min/max, use options `hAxis.minValue` and `hAxis.maxValue`...

Comment: gene b., have you get resolved this issue. Having same requirement. Can you please help me for this case.

Comment: Sameer: Yes, I didn't use Google Charts because it doesn't support a vertical timeline. I went with an HTML/JS template called "CodyHouse Schedule Template" which is a graphical timeline, similar to Outlook, and it was easy to expand and implement. Here's my summary of what I did: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46668526/1005607  Here's the link to that template, click Demo: https://codyhouse.co/gem/schedule-template/

Comment: ^ Also, here are some screenshots of my vertical timelines created with that "CodyHouse Template". (1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47039201/detecting-conflicts-on-a-timeline-part-2-isolate-true-overlaps (2)  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46778439/detecting-conflicts-on-a-scheduler-timeline-algorithm