# Detecting Conflicts on a Scheduler Timeline (Algorithm)

Tags: algorithm, sorting, recursion

Suppose I am plotting events with a `(StartTime,EndTime)` on a 24-hr Calendar similar to Outlook. My goal is to detect **overlaps (conflicts)** and split them up such that each column occupies N% of the width of the window, where N = total number of conflicts in that time frame.

My problem is, my algorithm

```
1) first, sort all events by StartTime
2) LOOP: looks at neighbors: CurrentEvent and NextEvent (n+1):

   if NextEvent exists {

      if (CurrentEvent EndTime > NextEvent StartTime) { // CONFLICT!
         overlappingMode = true;
         overlappingEvents.add(currentEvent); // Add to array
      }
      else {  // NO CONFLICT
         if (overlappingMode is TRUE) {
            // Resolve Now
            redrawOverlappingEvents(overlappingEvents);
            // Reset
            overlappingMode = false;
            EMPTY overlappingEvents;
         }
      }
   }

3) After the loop, also for the last element, 

   if (Overlap Mode is still TRUE) {
      overlappingEvents.add(currentEvent); // Add to array also
      // Now Resolve
      redrawOverlappingEvents(overlappingStartTimes);
      // Reset
      overlappingMode = false;
      EMPTY overlappingEvents;    
   }
```

This works most of the time but introduces a problem of some kind with EndTimes. For instance, consider the image below:

[image]

The last event should be part of the **Split-Group of 4** (not 3). It didn't get included in the Conflict Split because the previous Event's `EndTime` doesn't conflict with its `StartTime`.

In the Sorted array of StartTimes, the next-to-last event's `EndTime (4:30)` doesn't conflict with the last event's `StartTime (4:45)`. So the final event `4:45 - 6:00` didn't get included in the overall Split Group. I should have gotten a 4-column split layout for the time area spanning `02:30 - 06:00`.

Am I doing this algorithm correctly or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the "conflicts" relation isn't transitive, hence not an equivalence relation, but you want an equivalence relation so you can put them into equivalence classes that have the horizontal width shared. For this to work, we have to define a new relationship which is an equivalence relation (hence transitive) and then figure out how to compute it.

Getting an equivalence relation could be as easy as taking the transitive closure of your "conflicts" relation. That is, we can "add" all the missing members to make the relation transitive. One way to do this would be to keep your code largely the same, but instead of remembering the last start/end times, remember the first (hence earliest; we still need sorting) start time and the latest stop time, and to use that to detect "conflicts":

```
   // first event is the current event
   lastMaxEndTime = CurrentEvent EndTime

   if NextEvent exists {

      // if the maximum end time considered in
      // the conflicting component currently
      // under consideration extends beyond the
      // the next event's start time, then this
      // and everything that "conflicts" with it
      // is also defined to "conflict" with NextEvent
      if (lastMaxEndTime > NextEvent StartTime) { // CONFLICT!
         overlappingMode = true;
         overlappingEvents.add(currentEvent); // Add to array
         lastMaxEndTime = max(lastMaxEndTime, NextEvent EndTime)
      }
      else {  // NO CONFLICT
         if (overlappingMode is TRUE) {
            // Resolve Now
            redrawOverlappingEvents(overlappingEvents);
            // Reset
            overlappingMode = false;
            EMPTY overlappingEvents;
         }

         // everything that starts earlier than me,
         // ends before I start. so start over
         lastMaxEndTime = NextEvent EndTime
      }
   }
```

In your example, the algorithm does this:

```
lastMaxEndTime = 2:00
lastMaxEndTime > 2:30? no, so
    lastMaxEndTime = 3:30
lastMaxEndTime > 3:00? yes, so
    lastMaxEndTime = max(3:30, 5:00) = 5:00
lastMaxEndTime > 3:15? yes, so
    lastMaxEndTime = max(5:00, 4:30) = 5:00 <--- this fixed it
lastMaxEndTime > 4:45? yes, so
    lastMaxEndTime = max(5:00, 6:00) = 6:00
```

Comment: Yup this worked. Thanks so much! I'll still have to think about how the Max gets updated to prove this algorithm is correct -- I'll think about formal proof.

Comment: @geneb. If you get a formal proof, please post it! If you need help with one, let me know and I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Hi Patrick, I have a follow-up question about this algorithm, posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47039201/detecting-conflicts-on-a-timeline-part-2-isolate-true-overlaps  Any thoughts? thanks

Comment: @geneb. I commented and provided an answer on the other question. The other (earlier) answer by Prune is correct and easy to understand. I attempt a proof of Prune's answer and suggest another method (without proof that it is optimal).

Comment: Thanks a lot Patrick. Reviewing now, will accept/confirm in a few days. Really appreciate your help!