# Detecting Conflicts on a Timeline, Part 2: Isolate "True" Overlaps

Tags: algorithm, sorting, recursion

**This is a continuation of my original question about a Timeline-Scheduler Algorithm for plotting overlapping time conflicts:** **PART 1:** [Detecting Conflicts on a Scheduler Timeline (Algorithm)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46778439/detecting-conflicts-on-a-scheduler-timeline-algorithm)

I was given the correct algorithm, shown below, to split up "conflicting" events on  24-hr timeline such that each item in the conflict group occupies N% of the window.

My current problem (PART 2) is that conflicting events are treated as a group and always divided equally, but **the real goal is to only isolate "true conflicts" which are not necessarily the whole group**.

Consider the following picture.

[image]

Here, the original algorithm from [Part 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46778439/detecting-conflicts-on-a-scheduler-timeline-algorithm) gave a 3-way split for the events

```
12:30am - 1:30am
1:00am - 2:30am
2:00am - 4:00am
```

But this result is slightly incorrect. There are only 2 overlaps, and there should be 2 columns shown. Event #3 can be brought over to Column 1 since it doesn't conflict with Event #1. The only conflict (a max 2-way split) is that #1 conflicts with #2, and #3 also conflicts with #2. As the gray arrow shows, there should be 2 columns for this case.

Original Conflict-Detection Algorithm from Part 1:

```
 * 1) First sort all events by StartTime
 * 2) Initialize "lastMaxEndTime" to EndTime of First Event (#1)
 * 3) LOOP: For each Event: look at Current Event and Next Event (n+1)
 *          If Next Event Exists
 *              if (lastMaxEndTime > NextEvent StartTime) --> CONFLICT!
 *                  - set Overlap mode 
 *                  - push conflicting Current Event's StartTime into conflict array
 *                  - UPDATE: lastMaxEndTime = MAX(lastMaxEndTime, NextEvent EndTime)
 *              else --> NO CONFLICT
 *                  - if we are in Overlap Mode, this is the last overlap
 *                      - push this final conflicting Current Event's StartTime into conflict array
 *                      - draw overlaps now
 *                      - reset Overlap Mode and clear conflict array
 *                  - else
 *                      - this is a normal event, draw at 100%
 *                  - UPDATE: lastMaxEndTime = endTimeNext
 *                  
 *          Else (No Next Event, this is the last event)
 *                  - if we are in Overlap Mode, this is the last overlap
 *                      - push this final conflicting Current Event's StartTime into conflict array
 *                      - draw overlaps now
 *                      - reset Overlap Mode and clear conflict array
 *                  - else
 *                      - this is a normal event, draw at 100%
```

Or, a slightly different view of this pseudocode from Patrick's answer,

```
   // first event is the current event
   lastMaxEndTime = CurrentEvent EndTime

   if NextEvent exists {

      // if the maximum end time considered in
      // the conflicting component currently
      // under consideration extends beyond the
      // the next event's start time, then this
      // and everything that "conflicts" with it
      // is also defined to "conflict" with NextEvent
      if (lastMaxEndTime > NextEvent StartTime) { // CONFLICT!
         overlappingMode = true;
         overlappingEvents.add(currentEvent); // Add to array
         lastMaxEndTime = max(lastMaxEndTime, NextEvent EndTime)
      }
      else {  // NO CONFLICT
         if (overlappingMode is TRUE) {
            // Resolve Now
            redrawOverlappingEvents(overlappingEvents);
            // Reset
            overlappingMode = false;
            EMPTY overlappingEvents;
         }

         // everything that starts earlier than me,
         // ends before I start. so start over
         lastMaxEndTime = NextEvent EndTime
      }
   }
```

Comment: Prune's answer appears right. I attempted a proof of it. I also suggested, but did not prove, another approach you might prefer conceptually.

Answer (score 2):

You need to partition the events into "lanes", sequences of non-overlapping events.  This is generally easy with a "greedy" algorithm.  Consider the events in order.  For each event, place that event in the first "lane" (vertical column on your chart) where there is no overlap.  If the current event overlaps with all columns, then place it into a new column.

Comment: Could you take a look at the implementation I posted?

Comment: "take a look" to what end?  If the code doesn't work when you test it, post a new question.  If it works, but you want a code review, post it to CodeReview.StackExchange.com.  If there's something else appropriate for here, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Prune's answer is correct. Here is a proof.

In the base case of one event, the algorithm obviously gives an optimal solution of one lane with no overlaps.

Assume the algorithm gives an optimal solution for all numbers of events up to and including k.

We must show that the algorithm gives a correct result for k + 1 events. After k of these k + 1 events, the algorithm has built a schedule with optimally many lanes and no overlaps. It must now place the (k + 1)st event in some lane. Suppose that this event fits into some lane with no overlaps. In that case, place the event there, and the number of lanes must still be optimal (adding more events cannot result in needing *fewer* lanes). What if the (k + 1)st event overlaps with events in every existing lane?

The only way the (k + 1)st element can overlap with events in all existing lanes is if all existing lanes' latest running events overlap with each other. To see this must be true, consider that the start times are in ascending sorted order, so if any two of the existing lanes' latest running events didn't overlap with each other, the (k + 1)st event wouldn't overlap with the one of the two which finished earlier. But if we have a set of L + 1 events which all overlap with each other, we must have at least L + 1 lanes; one more than L, the optimal number of lanes given k events; and this is what the algorithm guarantees by placing the (k + 1)st element in a new lane in this instance.

Here is an alternative idea - you could fill up the lanes backwards using iterations of optimal event scheduling run in reverse; that is, add events with the latest start time to each lane while avoiding conflicts. This will give you as many non-overlapping events as possible in the first lane. Repeat the process iteratively on new lanes until you run out of events.

(Optimal event scheduling adds events to the schedule by choosing earliest stop time first, and then eliminating remaining events whose start times occur before the stop time chosen during the round. We can imagine time flowing in reverse and using latest start time while eliminating events with stop times after the chosen start time, taking the already sorted list in reverse order. Also, this iterated application of the optimal method should really be proven optimal in its own right, if it even is, but I digress.)

Comment: Thanks I posted an implementation of this algorithm. Does it look correct?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to implement this algorithm here.

I am considering a double-array `lanes[x][y]` where e.g.

```
lanes[0] = ["event1", "event4", "event7"]
lanes[1] = ["event2"]
```

etc.

**Algorithm:**

```
// Organize overlapping events into lanes where each lane has non-overlapping events from the conflict group
var lanes = [];

for (var i = 0; i < overlappingEventIDs.length; i++) {

   var currlane = 0;
   var laneFound = false;

   for (var j = 0; j < lanes.length; j++) {

    if (!laneFound) {
        var conflictInLaneFound = false;

        for (var k = 0; k < lanes[j].length; k++) {             
            if (!laneFound) {

                var testEventID = lanes[j][k];
                var testEventStartTime = getTime(testEventID.startTime);
                var testEventEndTime = getTime(testEventID.endTime);
                var thisStartTime = getTime(overlappingEventIDs[i].startTime);
                var thisEndTime = getTime(overlappingEventIDs[i].endTime);

                if (thisStartTime < testEventEndTime) {
                    conflictInLaneFound = true;
                }

            }
        }
        if (!conflictInLaneFound) {
            // Found a lane for this event, Lane #j
            lanes[j].push(overlappingEventIDs[i]);
            laneFound = true;               
        }
        else {
            // Increment currlane
            currlane++;                 
        }
    }
}

   if (!laneFound) {   // Need to put this in a new lane

     if (lanes[currlane] == undefined) {
        lanes.push([]);
     }
     lanes[currlane].push(overlappingEventIDs[i]);

   }

}
```

Comment: This is a little hard to follow for me. First off, I don't know why you check `laneFound` in the for loop, or why you use `currlane` rather than checking `lanes.length` when you need it. Other than that - it looks like you are checking all events in each lane, and putting the event in the first lane it fits into. if it doesn't fit in an existing lane, you create a new one and add it. This looks like it should work. Comments like "increment `currlane`" are not helpful; it's obvious that's what is happening. The question comments should answer is *why*.